# Converting string (hh:mm:ss) to integer

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I'm having a problem converting time in the `hh:mm:ss` format to an integer.

Using `JTextField` I enter time in the 24 hour format but I've used a string and don't know how to turn it into a integer.

My code

```
Date dNow = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat (" hh:mm:ss");
JTextField Stime = new JTextField(); 

String St = Stime.getText();      
Object[] message = {  "Insert Start Time (HH:MM:SS) ", Stime };
Stime.setText(ft.format(dNow));
```

I've used the `JTextField` because I'm going to allow the user to enter a different time within another `JTextField`and then calculate the difference

I can convert the string st into an integer and get no errors when I compile but lots of text when I run it which I think are caused by the semicolons but don't know how to fix it.

Comment: The next thing that is not clear: What conversion do you expect? Say the time is `12:00:00`, `00:00:00`, `06:00:00` or `06:01:00`. Which integers would you expect?

Comment: thanks for revisions, i didn't know i made so many mistakes. the code will write the time within the JTextField in the hh:mm:ss format and using another JTextField i can insert another time and then show the difference but i require to change the time into an integer and i dont know how to that simila to the "measuring elapsed time "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, use HH for 24 hour format. (You had a space in front too.)

```
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

Date answeredTime = ft.parse(st);
long asSecondsSince1970 = answeredTime.getTime();
```